# How to remove dropped items from RecyclerView in Android Pager 3?

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

I'm using [Android Paging 3 library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview). In my testing configuration it has a `PagingConfig` with `pageSize = 10` and `maxSize = 40`. When I scroll down the configured `RecyclerView`, everything works as expected - new portions of data are loaded when I'm getting close to the lower bound of the list. When we have too many data items loaded (more than the configured `maxSize`), it begins to be dropped - and it's an expected behaviour. But when I begin to scroll up, there are empty view holders without any data for these dropped items. That means the count of adapter's items doesn't change on the clean up of `PagingData`. How can I remove these dropped items (which are equal to `null`) from the `PagingDataAdapter`? Is there any API for this? If it should be done automatically, then my configuration of Paging 3 may be wrong. In this case I'll provide the code.

Comment: Looks like my configuration is correct - the official codelab for Paging 3 library does the same (null data models for dropped items) if we configure `maxSize` for it...

Comment: And the same thing for PagingWithNetworkSample from architecture-components-samples repo. Looks like the best thing I can do for now - is to disable `maxSize` restriction.

Comment: Looks like `retry()` method in `PagingDataAdapter` doesn't work too. There is no reaction when I call it after failed page fetching. Will use `refresh()` for now...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `PagingConfig.enablePlaceholders` set?

Disabling placeholders will prevent Paging from padding your lists with `null` items for pages that haven't loaded yet.

The default value for `PagingConfig.enablePlaceholders` is `true`.

Edit: While the above comment still holds since placeholders are represented as `null` items, this was actually a bug in alpha02, which has since been fixed and will go out with alpha03.

Comment: This option is set to `false` in my `PagingConfig`

Comment: Moreover setting `PagingConfig.enablePlaceholders` to `false` didn't change the described behaviour in PagingWithNetworkSample - checked right now

Comment: Step to reproduce: fetching the architecture-components-samples repo -> opening PagingWithNetworkSample project -> setting `maxSize = 90, enablePlaceholders = false` in `InMemoryByPageKeyRepository` -> running the app, scrolling more than 90 items to bottom -> scrolling to top again - there are empty items in forever "loading" state

Comment: Thanks, if what you're saying is true this is a bug on Paging's end. I tried to reproduce the issue here, but didn't succeed: https://github.com/dlam/architecture-components-samples/tree/so/62909698 I'm logging the result of the first item the adapter can present after each append. Either way, I've filed an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/161475289 to track progress on this and would be happy to re-open if you could upload a repro!

Comment: Note that I'm logging on APPEND in loadStateFlow as those events are guaranteed to be synchronous with adapter updates (there is an existing issue with initial load though).

Comment: My mistake - although disabling placeholders is still required to remove nulls (nulls are placeholders), I realized that this was actually a bug in alpha02 I fixed quite awhile ago. It will go out with alpha03 - https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1350887